# Does the current SYB permit extension of generic functions with new types?

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, scrap-your-boilerplate

The [first](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/hmap/hmap.ps) [two](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/hmap/gmap2.ps) Scrap Your Boilerplate papers describe a way of writing generic functions that work for general types, but have special cases for specific types.  For instance, [`fromJSON`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/aeson/0.6.1.0/doc/html/src/Data-Aeson-Generic.html#fromJSON) from the `aeson` package, defines a generic function for converting from JSON, but provides special cases for types like list or `Int`:

```
parseJSON :: (Data a) => Value -> Parser a
parseJSON j = parseJSON_generic j
             `ext1R` list
             `ext1R` vector
             `ext2R'` mapAny
             `ext2R'` hashMapAny
             -- Use the standard encoding for all base types.
             `extR` (value :: F Integer)
             `extR` (value :: F Int)
              ...
```

However, as [the third SYB paper](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/hmap/gmap3.pdf) notes, "all the type-specific cases [need] to be
supplied at once, when the recursive knot of generic function definition is tied".  The paper then proposes a way to lift this restriction through the type-class mechanism.

The first two SYB papers are (with some modifications) part of the [`syb`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb) package, but the third is not.  Is there some other way of lifting the restriction that all type-specific cases need to be specified at once with the implementation of SYB on Hackage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's, as far as I know, no way around the restriction within that system. The fact that there isn't is what necessitates introducing a new approach in the third paper. There's working syb-with-class code, implementing the third paper on hackage: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb-with-class

However, my recommendation these days would be to try to experiment with the new Generics mechanism, which is faster, more principled, and more flexible (albeit occasionally a real pain :-)).

Comment: Mhm.  My problem with the new Generics framework is that its a pain to reconstruct data if your encoding labels fields.  Anyway, thank you.